# GCM message stops foregrounded service

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using an indefinitely running service (with its own process) and an extension of GcmListenerService to receive push messages. The push messages will initiate an operation within the service.
The problem is, that if the app is closed/removed from the recently used app, the service is still running, but will stop immediately if a new message is received. The process list shows that first the background process is terminated and then a usual application process starts without any processing of the push message.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:allowBackup="false" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:process="domain.android.Application"
    android:name=".Application">
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="domain.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".service.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".service.BackgroundService"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:process="domain.android.service.BackgroundService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"/>
</application>
```

The GCM listener

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String code = data.getString("code");
        if ("j".equals(code)) {
            final String id = data.getString("id", null);
            String status = data.getString("status", null);

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), domain.android.service.BackgroundService.class);
            serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("method", "push");
            serviceIntent.putExtra("id", id);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("status", status);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("notificationId", (new Date()).getTime());
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The service:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("method")) {
            // Start processing
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        android.app.Notification.Builder builder = new android.app.Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))    
            .setContentText("Connected")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.marker_walker_white);

        android.app.Notification notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` in your manifest. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest

Comment: @KayAnn Thank you for your suggestion but the WAKE_LOCK permission is defined in my manifest. The problem seems to be a bug in android related to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried all workarounds but none worked with GCM. When a new message arrived, the new broadcast kills the app. @cki, did you resolve the problem?